# How to delete objects in ItemWriter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm using `spring-batch` for data imports. But during the `writer()` step, I don't want to persist the items processed, but delete them (by id) from a database.

Question: the `ItemWriters` like `JpaItemWriter` are just for persisting items. Is there any writer that I could eg pass a `CrudRepository` and that calls `repository.delete(id)`?

Comment: I don't this so; but write a custom one should be pretty easy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `JpaItemWriter` does not support deletions.  However...we do have a `RepositoryItemWriter` that you can configure the method called.  So in your case, you can use that in conjunction with a `JpaRepository` from Spring Data and configure the method to be called as a delete.  This would delete the items you pass in (if you were to delete by id, you'd want to create a processor that took the item and returned the id).  You can read more about the `RepositoryItemWriter` here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/data/RepositoryItemWriter.html

As an alternative, you could subclass the `JpaItemWriter` and override the `doWrite` method to call `entityManager.remove` instead of the `entityManager.merge` that it currently does...

Comment: probably not the right place here but I think u have a copy-paste-error in ur javadoc in the class description of the RepositoryItemWriter.